# remove non-user constant php

Tags: php, runkit, phpdbg

I'm  trying to remove the STDIN constant for debugging purposes, however

```
phpdbg> ev runkit_constant_remove('STDIN')
[PHP Warning:  runkit_constant_remove(): Only user defined constants may be removed. in eval()'d code on line 1]
```

So I would like to know whether there exists any way in php to remove these non-user constants.

Comment: Short answer: no. (custom extensions might do that, but I'm not aware of any)